# HTTP Cache-Control, how do I get Cache-Control: max-age = 0 header back from server?

Tags: html, http, caching, cache-control

To whom knows HTTP and HTML headers : I have a project for which I need to avoid the caching of a webpage. I have a basic knowledge of HTML, I found on the web that to avoid the caching I need to put some tags in the HTML code.
I put the following tags :

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

which I took on another post.
However, I still get my page cached for one hour by the servers and the HTTP header response from the server: Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Anyone have a cue ? How can I get Cache-Control: max-age=0 ? Anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: Although the idea of `<meta http-equiv=...` tags in HTML4 was for servers to convert them to real http headers, almost no servers ever did this. You should configure your server to send the real http headers by other means, which will depend on the server you are using.

Comment: Alohci, this is exactly what I found out after posting this... I modified the .htaccess file on the Apache server and it worked fine... this problem is now solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Alohci said in the comments section, the server didn't even look at the meta tags... After I modified the .htaccess file on the Apache server, it worked fine.

The meta tags are overridden by the server's http headers so it is of no help to put them... instead, modify the http headers sent by the server. The method to do this varies according to which server you're using. On apache servers, there is a .htaccess file controlling the caching of the pages.